# How to set up a server for my app

Tags: api, parse-platform, server, backend

At the moment I am making an app. I am relatively new but have experience with a lot of different languages like PHP and SQL. My app needs to communicate with a server to post/retrieve data for everyone to see. People also need to be able to login and register. Right now I am using parse because it gives a lot of the requirements in an easy package but parse is retiring soon and I have no experience with setting up my own server.

I was thinking of making my own 'server' from an old computer but not use parse because it will no longer support push notification. Then of course the app needs to communicate with this server. I started looking online and found a lot of terms but not a real clear explanation on how to proceed. I need it to be able to communicate with iOS and Android. Furthermore I was wondering how to execute a script on the server itself. I want to do something with time, once someone uploads something it needs to disappear after 48 hours, but of course it also needs to do this even if the app isn't active on a smartphone

Can anyone tell me how I need to proceed, what to use and where i can find useful info.

My plan for now is creating my own server with something like MongoDB but then i still need something called a backend and different SDK's to communicate with the apps. Maybe its possible to install parse on my own server and add something so i can still use Push and run a script on the server itself.

All help would be very much App-reciated ;)!

Comment: You can get a high-quality VPS from a provider like Digital Ocean for $5 a month and you might find that's cheaper than paying for power for some old computer. They also have templates for spinning up a server that's configured with things like MongoDB out of the box, saving you considerable trouble. The biggest problem with home servers is that their IP address changes unpredictably.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of a backend service or framework is to let developer focus on front end app development. Maybe you can check other options like firebase, meoter, or even leancloud. Don't be hurry jump to the decision to make your own backend.

Comment: Ok so I dont need to make a backend but use one that already exists, are these free and can i use these in combination with my own server?

Answer (score 1):

Parse Server is already supporting Push Notifications. I think should keep using Parse. It will become the best framework for backend and API development in a short time. You can also use services like https://www.back4app.com that helps you in all process of configuration of your server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by create your own server running a personal derver pr you mean create your own back end application?

Comment: I would prefer not to have to make my own backend application, i think i want to use an existing one but i dont know which one and how to let it communicate with a server

The open source parse server would be great but it removed quite a bit of handy features like push

Comment: Ok i just see they do support push, my bad

Comment: Why dont you try to use laravel or dingo api which is based on laravel. Larvel provides a lot of functionalitoes out of the box that will help you deploy a simple api in a very short time.